# Why can't I see smoke in the viewport when using Eevee?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I organised nodes as shown to make the smoke emit light according to its density. What happens is a change of all the world background to white, although I've changed it to black. smoke doesn't appear.

[image]

When I change emission strength simply as a value (not by nodes) the same thing happens. (Note: I have no light source, I want the smoke to be emitting light.)